# 'Warning: Can\'t perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: react-native

im building a react native application ,still i have 2 screens 
1.Enter mobile
2.Verify Otp

**EnterUserInfo.js**

```
class UserInfoInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { formValid:true,
                   validMobileNumber:false,
                   .
                   .}}


   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if(nextProps.common.isFetching===false) {
         this.props.navigation.navigate('VerifyOtpScreen')
         .
         .
       } else {
       this.setState({isLoading:true})
          }} 

  onPressNext=()=> {
         this.props.sendOtp(payload)}

  render() {
    return (<View/>) 
   }
   }


 }
function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
    common: state.common
      }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
  ...bindActionCreators({ sendOtp }, dispatch)
   }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(UserInfoInput);
```

Here user enter the phone number ,and trigger an action sendOtp,response will be in the reducer and it will be available in the componentwillrecieveprops() lifecycle.

**VerifyOtp.js**

```
class VerifyOtp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { oneTimePIN: '' ,
                      .};
      }

  componentDidMount(){
         this.setState({ phoneNumber:this.props.common.phone});
       }

   componentWillMount() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ isResendDisabled: false, opacity: 1 });
      }, 30000);
    }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  //do operation 
  }

    onPressNext=()=>{
      if(this.state.oneTimePIN=='') {
      this.setState({showNotification:true})
      } 
      else {
        this.onSubmit()
      }
    }

  onSubmit=()=>{
       this.props.verifyOtp(payload) 

     }
 onResendOtp=()=>{

      this.props.sendOtp(payload,locationData) 

      this.setState({ isResendDisabled: true, opacity: 0.5 });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ isResendDisabled: false, opacity: 1 });
      }, 30000);

    }

   render() {
        return (<View><Elements></View>)
       }

}
 function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
          common: state.common
    }
  }
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
          ...bindActionCreators({ verifyOtp,sendOtp }, dispatch)
      }
    }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(VerifyOtp);
 VerifyOtp screen used to verify the otp.
```

The problem is,If i move back to  enterUserinfo screen and move again to the verifyOtp screen im getting the warning message

> 'Warning: Can\'t perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application
>     What is the reason for the warning , and how tackle the issue?

Comment: Its because you are trying to setState on an unmounted component. You redirect to other component but after say 3s setTimeout callback is called and tries to setState on component that is unmounted. You need to cancel timeout in `componentWillUnmount`lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you call an async function followed by setstate.
A simple work around would be like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    ...
    this.isCancelled: false
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    !this.state.isCancelled && this.setState({ isResendDisabled: false, 
      opacity: 1 });
  }, 30000);
}
```

and in `componentWillUnmount`

```
componentWillUnmount() {
// setting it true to avoid setState waring since componentWillMount is async
this.state.isCancelled = true;
}
```